# SF2 Flash Messages not showing from FlashBag

Tags: php, session, symfony, flash-message

I am attempting to output a flash message to the screen using the [FlashBagInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBagInterface.html), however I am having no luck in doing so.

This is my current setup, as you can see my controller sets the message and then my Twig template is attempting to output it. In practice i'm only going to have one message on this page, so a `for` loop is probably not required but I can't see why this code is not working for me.

I don't get any errors, just nothing output to the screen.

Also, if I `die` out in the code on `$message` I get my message that I want to show.

In my controller:

```
$message = $this->get('translator')->trans('ContactThanksMessage');
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('contact_thanks', array('message' => $message));
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("ayrshireminis_contact"));
```

In my Twig template:

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.get('contact_thanks') %}
    {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('contact_thanks') %}
       <p>{{ flashMessage }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to know is when you get a flash message, it is removed in a auto expire strategy (the default one). So, in your template when you do your `if`, the flash message is removed with the `get` method... You should rely on the `has` method to check if the flash message exists and then use `get` to consume it.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was initially following an old tutorial which used the deprecated `app.session.flash.get` method. Changing to `has` and then `get` does the job!